# Kernel compilation error recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, compiling

I am compiling the latest kernel cloned from Linus's git repository for a challenge. Here are the steps I followed,
1. Installed cross compilation tools

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential kernel-package fakeroot libncurses5-dev
```

2. cloned the latest git repository

```
$ git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

3. Copied the current build configuration to the root of the source tree and updated the configuration file.

```
yes '' | make oldconfig
```

4. `make clean`
5. Made the linux image and header .deb files

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
```

After a few minutes of compilation, it shows the error

```
dpkg-genchanges: warning: package linux-firmware-image-4.2.0-rc3-custom listed in files list but not in control info
dpkg-genchanges: warning: package linux-headers-4.2.0-rc3-custom listed in files list but not in control info
dpkg-genchanges: warning: package linux-headers-4.3.0-rc1-eudyptula listed in files list but not in control info
dpkg-genchanges: warning: package linux-image-4.2.0-rc3-custom-dbg listed in files list but not in control info
dpkg-genchanges: warning: package linux-image-4.3.0-rc1-eudyptula listed in files list but not in control info
dpkg-genchanges: warning: package linux-image-4.2.0-rc3-custom listed in files list but not in control info
dpkg-genchanges: warning: package linux-image-4.3.0-rc1-eudyptula-dbg listed in files list but not in control info
dpkg-genchanges: warning: package linux-firmware-image-4.3.0-rc1-eudyptula listed in files list but not in control info
dpkg-genchanges: error: package linux-image-4.2.0-rc3-custom-dbg has section kernel in control file but debug in files list
scripts/package/Makefile:91: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed
make[1]: *** [deb-pkg] Error 255
Makefile:1226: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed
make: *** [deb-pkg] Error 2
```

I think the error has occurred in the making of .deb package. I really don't understand the error message

```
 linux-image-4.2.0-rc3-custom-dbg has section kernel in control file but debug in files list
```

What does it really means?. Please help!

Answer (score 5):

First, the `yes '' | make oldconfig` step is more easily done by way of `make olddefconfig`.

Having said that,

What happens is that the kernel's `Makefile` generates a number of files inside a `debian/` directory which are not completely following [the spec](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/). Combined with a gradual stricter enforcement of this spec in the build tools over the years, means that a hack which used to work in the past (generating `.deb` packages which aren't listed in `debian/control`, or which are listed but whose details differ) don't work anymore these days.

Personally, I recommend against the `make deb-pkg` method of building a Debian package of a vanilla kernel. If you want to do that, a method which works better IME is to use the `kernel-package` package which is part of Debian proper:

```
apt install kernel-package fakeroot
cd /path/to/git/checkout
make defconfig
make-kpkg --rootcmd fakeroot kernel_image
```

This should get you a package (with the `.config` file you created) that you can install on your Debian system.

Comment: "make-kpkg --rootcmd fakeroot make-kpkg kernel_image" shows error "Error: Unknown target make-kpkg 
use --targets to display help on valid targets". So I used "fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers". Now it's compiled succesfully. I installed all the generated deb packages using  "dpkg -i *.deb" but the new kernel is not booting up !

Comment: That probably means you need to switch some .config options; Debian assumes a few things, some of which may not be part of the default configuration. This is a different problem, however, so I would suggest you ask a new question about that (and that you add some details about the failure to boot...)

Comment: Updated to remove my mistake...

Comment: @WouterVerheist  Can you answer this question ? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238469/difference-between-make-kpkg-and-make-deb-pkg

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same problem as you, and solved it by cherry-picking [this patch](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/8d740a37b92f3d4a0435fe263b32efc7f61c5efb) into my tree:

It looks like it could also be solved by doing

```
rm -f debian/files
```