# Difference between make-kpkg and make deb-pkg

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, compiling, make

I would like to know the exact difference between `make-kpkg` and `make deb-pkg` . [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376824/difference-between-make-kpkg-and-make-deb-pkg) asks almost the same thing but with no satisfying answers. Previously I was using

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg
```

to compile the kernel source tree and to generate header+kernel-image debian packages. I found that it is extremely slow as it takes more than 1 hour to compile on my 2nd gen Intel i3  CPU. Then I found another method using `make-kpkg` which is 5-6 times faster than `deb-pkg` method I used before. The code I run

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers  -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`
```

and it takes only just 10-15 minutes to compile and generate the deb packages. In both the compilation process, jobs are divided for `_NPROCESSORS_ONLN` then what makes this difference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `make-kpkg` is maintained by that script writer (most likely those Debian people), and `make deb-pkg` is maintained by the kernel guys. The Debian people may know more.

Comment: Additionally, those backticks in your command is failing in stackexchange. Either wrap two backticks around those commands or use `-j $(getconf blah)` instead of ``-j `getconf blah` ``.

Comment: @Arthur2e5, correct.  Also, when it comes to integrating `linux-image-*.deb` and `linux-headers-*.deb` etc into the distribution, the `make-kpkg` tool is far more likely to be updated to take advantage of other kernel related helpers in the distro (e.g. `dkms` and `update-initramfs` and others).  The kernel `Makefile` `deb-pkg` target probably only gets worked on if it breaks.

Comment: BTW the fastest way for binary only kernel package is `bindeb-pkg` target.

Answer (score 8):

`make-kpkg` is (being) retired, the official Debian way is `make deb-pkg`.
The official [Debian kernel handbook](https://kernel-handbook.debian.net/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-building) uses `make deb-pkg`.

`make-kpkg` is included in [wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=wheezy&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=make-kpkg) and [jessie](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=make-kpkg) but stretch (current stable) only contains it [for powerpc](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=make-kpkg).

Powerpc is no longer supported in buster (testing), and unsurprisingly the only hit for filenames containing `make-kpkg`is an [autocompletion info file for zsh](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=make-kpkg).

That would clearly indicate which one of both is the preferred option of Debian.

(However, if you are testing what works and what not, recompiling a lot, you may want to remove the "make clean" from `scripts/packages/Makefile` as a first step.  After all, even make-kpkg is aimed at creating a Debian package from a working kernel source and config, not kernel programming and debugging.)

Comment: FYI `kernel-package` into which belong `make-kpkg` [has been removed from testing](https://tracker.debian.org/news/847350/kernel-package-removed-from-testing/) in June 2017, but [added again into unstable](https://tracker.debian.org/news/857223/accepted-kernel-package-13018nmu1-source-into-unstable/) and [testing](https://tracker.debian.org/news/858446/kernel-package-13018nmu1-migrated-to-testing/) the same month. More info: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/kernel-package. But I agree it's better to use `make deb-pkg`.

Comment: no more `kernel-package` on debian 10, please someone bring it back.